# Clarification on wording of a problem in Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently working on problem 11 in section 1.1 of Hungerford's graduate text, which is to show 5 conditions of a group are equivalent. However, I'm not exactly sure what the last condition means:

> $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all $a,b \in G$ and for three consecutive integers $n$.

Does this mean for a given integer $n$, $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, $(ab)^{n+1} = a^{n+1}b^{n+1}$, and $(ab)^{n+2} = a^{n+2}b^{n+2}$ are all true? If so, isn't that just same as saying $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He means that there exists an integer $n$ such that $a^kb^k=(ab)^k$ holds for $k=n,n+1,n+2$, and any $a,b$.

Comment: Ah I see, it was the "there exists" part I wasn't getting from the wording. Thank you very much!